# Inner Product Space Puzzle

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, inner-products

**Question:** Let $V$ be a real inner product space, and let $\mathbf{u}, \mathbf{v} \in V$ be such that:
$$\left\lVert\mathbf{u}\right\rVert = 3, \qquad \left\lVert\mathbf{u}+\mathbf{v}\right\rVert =4, \qquad \left\lVert\mathbf{u}-\mathbf{v}\right\rVert = 6.$$
Find $\left\lVert\mathbf{v}\right\rVert$.

I don't know exactly why, but I am kinda stuck on this. My main attempts have involved using $\left\lVert\mathbf{u}\right\rVert = \sqrt{\left\langle\mathbf{u},\mathbf{u}\right\rangle}$, followed by a bunch of algebraic manipulation and the application of vector space rules in an attempt to isolate $\left\langle\mathbf{v}, \mathbf{v}\right\rangle$.

Any hints/tips would be appreciated.

Comment: Use the [parallelogram law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallelogram_law#The_parallelogram_law_in_inner_product_spaces).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We know
$$
\langle u + v, u + v \rangle = 16\quad\text{and}\quad \langle u - v, u - v\rangle = 36
$$
Therefore,
$$
\langle u + v, u + v \rangle + \langle u - v, u - v \rangle = 2\langle u, u \rangle + 2 \langle v, v\rangle = 52
$$
Now since $\langle u, u \rangle = 9$, we have
$$
\langle v, v\rangle = 17
$$

Comment: I'm pretty sure I got that exact result a while back, but it seemed kinda strange to me and I questioned myself. Will look back over my working. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In every inner product space we have:

$||u+v||^2+||u-v||^2=2||u||^2+2||v||^2$

From

$\left\lVert\mathbf{u}\right\rVert = 3, \qquad \left\lVert\mathbf{u}+\mathbf{v}\right\rVert =4, \qquad \left\lVert\mathbf{u}-\mathbf{v}\right\rVert = 6$

we get $||v||^2=17$